# Adding an if statement to a Stack Navigatior in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, parameters, expo, react-navigation-v5

I have a "chat" screen that can be accessed from multiple screens in my React Native App.  I am trying to add an "if statement" with a "route.params?" to the stack navigator, so it will navigate the user back to the proper screen, depending on where they are coming from, but I cannot get the "if statement" to execute.

Below is my code:

```
    function MainTabScreen ({ navigation, route }){
      
      const didComeFromNextScreen = () => route.params
      const didComeFromOtherScreen = () => route.params
      
    
      const chatChecker = ()=>{
    
        if(route.params?.didComeFromNextScreen){
          console.log('It came from NextScreen')
          navigation.navigate('NextScreen')
        return;
        }
    
        if(route.params?.didComeFromOtherScreen){
          console.log('It came from OtherScreen')
          navigation.navigate('OtherScreen')
        return;
        }
    
      }
 
      <MainTab.Navigator screenOptions ={{
              headerStyle:{
                  backgroundColor:"#fff" ,        
                },
                gestureEnabled: false,
                headerTintColor: 'red', 
                headerTitleStyle: {
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  fontSize: height*0.023,
                  textAlign: 'center',
                }
            }}
       >
    
    
        <MainTab.Screen name = "NextScreen" component={NextScreen} options= {{
                title: '' ,
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerLeft: null,
                headerRight: () => (
                  <Icon.Button name = "message" size={25} backgroundColor= "#fff" onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('ChatScreen',{
                  didComeFromNextScreen: true
                })}> 
        </Icon.Button>
              }}
    />
        
        <MainTab.Screen name = "ChatScreen" component={ChatScreen} options= {{
                title: '' ,
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerLeft: ()=>(
                <Icon.Button name = "arrow-left" size={25} backgroundColor= "#fff" onPress={chatChecker}/>          
                )
              }}
    />
    
        <MainTab.Screen name = "OtherScreen" component={OtherScreen} options= {{
                title: '' ,
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerLeft: null,
                headerRight: () => (
onPress={ () => navigation.navigate('ChatScreen',{
                  didComeFromOtherScreen: true
                })}> 

              }}
    />
        
        </MainTab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you made these functions but functions will always be true so it wont work

```
const didComeFromNextScreen = () => route.params
const didComeFromOtherScreen = () => route.params
```

update to

```
const didComeFromNextScreen = route.params
const didComeFromOtherScreen = route.params
```

Comment: This didn't work, and still will not allow me to navigate backwards